# How do you choose an optimal PlainModulus in SEAL?

Tags: seal

I am currently learning how to use SEAL and in the parameters for BFV scheme there was a helper function for choosing the PolyModulus and CoeffModulus and however this was not provided for choosing the PlainModulus other than it should be either a prime or a power of 2 is there any way to know which optimal value to use?

In the given example the PlainModulus was set to parms.PlainModulus = new SmallModulus(256); Is there any special reason for choosing the value 256?

Answer (score 2):

In BFV, the `plain_modulus` basically determines the size of your data type, just like in normal programming when you use 32-bit or 64-bit integers. When using `BatchEncoder` the data type applies to each slot in the plaintext vectors.

How you choose `plain_modulus` matters a lot: the noise budget consumption in multiplications is proportional to `log(plain_modulus)`, so there are good reasons to keep it as small as possible. On the other hand, you'll need to ensure that you don't get into overflow situations during your computations, where your encrypted numbers exceed `plain_modulus`, unless you specifically only care about correctness of the results modulo `plain_modulus`.

In almost all real use-cases of BFV you should want to use `BatchEncoder` to not waste plaintext/ciphertext polynomial space, and this requires `plain_modulus` to be a prime. Therefore, you'll probably want it to be a prime, except in some toy examples.